# What whole number $n$ satisfies: $ n<\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}} < n+1 $

Tags: number-theory, inequality

**Problem**

> As the title says: What whole number $n$ satisfies $$ n<\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}} < n+1 $$

**My attempt at answer, which is not rigorous at all**

Let's try to calculate the middle part. We make the approximation that $\sqrt{42} ≈ 7$. Substituting this value gives:

$\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+7}} = \sqrt{42+\sqrt{49}}=\sqrt{42+7}=\sqrt{49}=7 $

However, since we approximated this doesn't really equate to $7$. But the actual value must be between $6$ and $7$. Let's call the actual number $a, \: a\in]6;7[$

Now the inequality looks like this:

$$ n < a < n+1, \: \: a \in]6;7[$$

From here it's easy to see that $n=6$ is the only whole number that satisfies the inequality.

**My question**

My attempt at an answer wasn't very analytic or rigouros, nor do I know if it is right. Is there a way to solve the problem more elegantly that doesn't rely on my silly idea of bad approximations?

Comment: $42$ is nearer six and a half than six.

Comment: Notice that the integer part of the number is equal to $n$

Comment: Just squaring once will give you answer...

Comment: $6<\sqrt{42}<\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+7}}=7$ all the inequalities can be proved by squaring.

Comment: Your idea isn't silly at all.  You just need to just need to write it a bit better.  What you have shown is that since $\sqrt{42}<7$ it follows that $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<7$.  And of course $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}>\sqrt{42}>\sqrt{36}=6$, so you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct:

1. Since $\sqrt{42}<7$, $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<7$.
2. Since $\sqrt{42}>6$, $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}>\sqrt{48}>6$,
   so $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}>\sqrt{48}>6$.

So $n=6$.

Comment: This was a quick and good answer and exactly what I was looking for. It's a joy asking questions on this site, everyone is so competent and professional!

Comment: @JCAA I may be missing something but I don't see how $\sqrt{42}<7$ implies $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<7$. Because $\sqrt{43}<7$, but $\sqrt{43+\sqrt{43+\sqrt{43}}}>7$

Comment: $\sqrt{42}<7$ therefore $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}<\sqrt{49}=7$, so $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<\sqrt{49}=7$. It has been mentioned in the OP, essentially.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x$ equal to the infinite nested root $\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+...}}}$

Then $x^2=n+x$, so we have $x\cdot(x-1)=n$

So, whenever $n$ is the product of two consecutive integers, the infinite radical is equal to the larger of the two integers.

It so happens that $42=6\times7$, therefore $\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+...}}}=7$

Since your expression is not infinite, but is truncated, that means the value of your expression is less than $7$, and it is clearly greater than $6$ because $\sqrt{42}>6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $6 < \sqrt{42} < 7$. Use this to find $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Can we check this: I think that $6<\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}$ is obvious, but
$\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<7$ isn't. But
\begin{align}
\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}}<7&\iff 42+\sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}<49\\
&\iff \sqrt{42+\sqrt{42}}<7\\
&\iff 42+\sqrt{42}<49\\
&\iff \sqrt{42}<7\\
&\iff 42<49
\end{align}
which is true. And we can do this for any number of nestings with $\sqrt{42}$.