# If $E(X)=0$, does it mean that $E(X^{2k-1})=0, $ for all $k$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A quick question I was just wondering about:

If we have some random variable $X$, such that $E(X)=0$, will it always satisfy that $E(X^3)=0$, $E(X^5)=0,..., E(X^{2k-1})=0$ for all $k>0$?

If not, can you think of a counter-example?

Comment: $P(X=-1)=2/3$ and $P(X=2)=1/3$.

Comment: Beat me. ${}{}$

Comment: That said, it is in fact true for symmetric distributions, if the moments exist

Comment: @Astyx good one! Thank you

Comment: @ayeayemaung I'll remember that, thank you!

Comment: @ryden So here you have a simple conjecture, yet you tried zero examples to test the conjecture?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What about $X=3$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, and $X=-3/2$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: You win:) nice.. @ayeayemaung just said that it's true for symmetric distributions. Thank you!

Comment: Why $3$? Why not take values $1$ and $-{1 \over 2}$?

Comment: @copper.hat lucky number maybe?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Like, why not $42$?

Comment: @copper.hat missed opportunity

Comment: @copper.hat that would have also answered everything else on this site in one fell swoop

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I do see the number 42 in a variety of answers. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799926/what-whole-number-n-satisfies-n-sqrt42-sqrt42-sqrt42-n1